# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toLowerCase') , const keys =["type, name"]

Tags: reactjs, express

Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toLowerCase')

```
  const keys =["type, name"]
  const search = () => {
  return totalCar.filter((item) => keys.some((key) => 
  item[key].toLowerCase().includes(query)));
          };
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change one string

```
const keys = ["type, name"];
```

To two strings

```
const keys = ["type", "name"];
```